# Image work fine I Chrome but not IE

Tags: c#, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, responsive

I have two images beside each other on my page right side. It works perfectly in Chrome and shows correct but in Internet Edge the pictures is HUGE. What have I missed?

The code is following:

```
text = "<div><center><table style=\"width:100%;\">" +
        "<tbody><tr>" +
        "<td align=\"left\">" +
        "<a href=\"http://www." + test + "/m.aspx\"><center><img style=\"display: block; height: auto;max-width: 95%;margin: 0 auto;\" src=\"/images/" + entryM.Image + "\"></center></a>" +
        "</td>" +
        "<td align=\"right\">" +
        "<a href=\"http://www." + test + "/test/" + entryR.url + "\" target=\"_blank\"><center><img style=\"display: block; height: auto;max-width: 95%;margin: 0 auto;\" src=\"/images/" + 
entryR.Image + "\"></center></a>" +
        "</td> " +
        "</tr>" +
        "<tr>" +
        "<td style=\"text-align:center;\">test</td>" +
        "<td style=\"text-align:center;\">test</td>" +
        "</tr>" +
        "</tbody></table>" +
        "<table style=\"width:100%; margin-bottom: 30px;\">" +
        "<tbody><tr>" +
        "<td style=\"text-align:center;\">" +
        "<a href=\"http://www." + test + "/m.aspx\"><u>test</u></a>" +
        "</td>" +
        "</tr>" +
        "</tbody></table>" +
        "</center></div>";
```

Comment: A demo would be very useful to see the problem. I think the table layout will be the key to solve this...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `width: 50%` to both the images

```
<img style=\"display: block; height: auto; width: 50%; max-width: 95%;margin: 0 auto;\" src=\"/images/" + entryM.Image + "\">
```

Comment: still same :/ both images is huge in IE , but works perfectly in Chrome

Comment: In that case try giving width in px(eg: 250px)

Comment: doesnt work. My page i also responsive, so if i make the windows smaller in chrome the pictures also shows correct. But in IE images a HUGE

Answer (score 0):

```
 @supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
  /* edge*/
  .img{
    max-height: 92px;//img height
  }
 }

  @media all and (-ms-high-contrast:none){
    /* ie*/
    .img{
      height: 43px;//img height
    }
  }
```

Comment: IE and edge have a problem with height in flex box and tables. they try to fill the container  `height: auto` and IE does not support max-height @Koopakiller @Mykremin